# clBuildProgram failed with error code -11 and without build log

Tags: opencl

I have worked little bit in OpenCL now but recently "clBuildProgram" failed in one of my program. My code excerpt is below:

```
cl_program program;
program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char**) &kernel_string, NULL, &err);
if(err != CL_SUCCESS)
{
cout<<"Unable to create Program Object. Error code = "<<err<<endl;
exit(1);
}
if(clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) != CL_SUCCESS)
{
cout<<"Program Build failed\n";
size_t length;
char buffer[2048];
clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device_id[0], CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, sizeof(buffer), buffer, &length);
cout<<"--- Build log ---\n "<<buffer<<endl;
exit(1);
}
```

Normally earlier I got syntax or other errors inside kernel file here with the help of "clGetProgramBuildInfo()" function whenever "clBuildProgram" Failed but when this program runs, on console it only prints:

Program Build failed
--- Build log ---

And when I tried to print the error code returned by "clBuildProgram"; it is "-11"......
What can be the problem with my kernel file that I dont get any build fail information ?

Answer (score 10):

You can learn the meaning of OpenCL error codes by searching in cl.h.  In this case, -11 is just what you'd expect, CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE.  It's certainly curious that the build log is empty.  Two questions:

1.) What is the return value from clGetProgramBuildInfo?

2.) What platform are you on?  If you are using Apple's OpenCL implementation, you could try setting CL_LOG_ERRORS=stdout in your environment.  For example, from Terminal:

$ CL_LOG_ERRORS=stdout ./myprog

It's also pretty easy to set this in Xcode (Edit Scheme -> Arguments -> Environment Variables).

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the C instead of C++:

```
err = clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL); 

////////////////Add the following lines to see the log file///////////

if (err != CL_SUCCESS) {
char *buff_erro;
cl_int errcode;
size_t build_log_len;
errcode = clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, devices[0], CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, 0, NULL, &build_log_len);
if (errcode) {
            printf("clGetProgramBuildInfo failed at line %d\n", __LINE__);
            exit(-1);
        }

    buff_erro = malloc(build_log_len);
    if (!buff_erro) {
        printf("malloc failed at line %d\n", __LINE__);
        exit(-2);
    }

    errcode = clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, devices[0], CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, build_log_len, buff_erro, NULL);
    if (errcode) {
        printf("clGetProgramBuildInfo failed at line %d\n", __LINE__);
        exit(-3);
    }

    fprintf(stderr,"Build log: \n%s\n", buff_erro); //Be careful with  the fprint
    free(buff_erro);
    fprintf(stderr,"clBuildProgram failed\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: +1: In my case the returned log size was 25kB and I allocated 1kB for it! Then I got back the log and turned out that the file is in UTF-8 format, which is wrong!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem with an empty log file. I was testing my ocl kernel on a different computer. It had 2 platforms instead of one. One Intel GPU and one AMD GPU. I only had AMD OCL SDK installed. Installing the Intel OCL SDK fixed the problem. Also selecting the AMD platform instead of the Intel GPU platform fixed it.

Comment: I changed my program to use the AMD GPU, and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen on OSX 10.14.6 when the OpenCL kernel source is missing the `_kernel` attribute tag. If both the `_kernel` tag and return type are missing it seems to crash the system OpenCL compiler daemon, which then takes a few seconds to restart before new kernels will compile again.