# --disregard!-- OSX OpenCL -- drivers past 10.8.5 fail to build previously working kernel: Compile Server Error

Tags: xcode, macos, opencl

{disregard; see my answer below}

I have a kernel that's worked for years under the drivers Apple ships with os 10.7.4 and 10.8.5.  I finally decided to bring my macbook pro 2012 up to date, and with it XCode and my project.

The drivers Apple ships with El Capitan (10.10) and Sierra (10.11) now give the dreaded Compile Server error when calling clCreateProgramWithSource.  I've tried downloading nVidia's newer released drivers for those OSs and get the same failure.

I'm thinking that this is due to complexity (this is also mentioned in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30000473/compile-server-error-while-building-opencl-kernels)).  My kernel is maybe 2000 lines without comments and maybe a few hundred less without unused #ifs.

The real kicker is that it *used to* work!

This is a function of the driver, right, not the OS?  Did nVidia reduce the heap size, allowing less of a stack of logic to be compiled?  Is there a parameter I can pass to give it a bigger heap, or whatever; obviously the hardware is capable of it.  Do I try to file a bug report with nVidia? with Apple?

(clCreateProgramWithSource still works on the CPU. I have an AMD card in a Pro and am curious whether the newer systems break that compiler too; it's still running 10.8.5.)

[EDIT: I have to say that I misspoke earlier. clCreateProgramWithSource returns almost immediately with no error. The problem comes in clBuildProgram after about 2 minutes of compile time....]

Comment: Can you get a build log from the failing compile process (like through `clGetProgramBuildInfo`)?

Comment: I'm afraid that the entire contents of the build log is: "Compile Server Error.<cr>"!  (I do have to say that I misspoke earlier, though. clCreateProgramWithSource returns almost immediately with no error.  The problem comes in clBuildProgram after about 2 minutes of compile time....)

Comment: [Seems like it might be an OSX Issue.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30000473/compile-server-error-while-building-opencl-kernels)

Comment: Thanks; solved.  Was not a driver problem; the order of the devices had changed and I had assumed based on position in the list.

Comment: Please find the answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852581/clbuildprogram-failed-with-error-code-11-and-without-build-log/7853365#7853365

Answer (score 0):

Please disregard!!!!

The source of the error was something else entirely:

Under the older OSs, the discrete GPU showed as the second device_id.  At least from 10.10 on, it's listed as the *first* device.  My code was trying to build for dev_id[1], which now yields the Intel integrated GPU.

I still don't know why it wouldn't build for that one, but that's not what's needed anyway, and it does in fact build correctly for the nVidia 650m when properly asked.

Apologies for having wasted anyone's bandwidth on this . . . !